# Is it possible to set all JPanes the same background color at once?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a little game. I know how to set a background color to a JPanel.

```
pane.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

My problem is, I've a BorderPane as layout and if I want to place something in the south I need to create a new JPane. Foreach pane I create i need to set the background color again. My Question is, is it possible to set the background color for every pane at once?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ... and welcome to upvote levels by the way ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the nice idea from Antiossss, you could do one of these two, too:

- typically, any UI container knows about its children. So you can write some generic code that (probably recursively) fetches the children of some UI component, and if it is a JPanel, set the background
- probably easier to do: your code simply *remembers* all JPanels you care about itself

In other words: when you want to treat a number of "things" in similar ways, then easiest solution is to have a field

```
Set<JPanel> myPanels = new HashSet<>();
```

in some of your "root" classes, and every time you create a panel ... you add it to that set, so that when you need them you can go:

```
for(JPanel aPanel : myPanels) { aPanel.setBackground(...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always set color of the main container to the red, and then make all your panels transparent with `setOpaque(false)`;

Comment: That's a nice idea, and thanks for leaving some "space" for another answer ;-)